# Question about convergence of a series with a minus sign in front?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been taught that convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is equivalent to convergence of the sequence of partial sums $(\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. This was how convergence of a series was defined.

My question is (And this probably is obvious, but I am unsure since I know series don't behave in the same way as finite summations do) is convergence of the series $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ equivalent to convergence of the sequence $(-\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Also, would it be correct to say $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-a_n$ for some sequence $a_n$? That is, would it be correct to say that these two series are the same series?

Comment: yes of course...

Comment: My only caveat would be that I would read $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ as the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, evaluated in the limit, and *then* changed in sign. But since it is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-a_n$, all your ways lead to the exact same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we write  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, even if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n$ does not converge....so what would be the meaning of $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ ? Of cousre, in case this happens it, we can prove that  $m \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m a_n$ , for any real number $m$.